# Website stuck on loading screen for an async call

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-side Blazor Webapp with an async RestSharp RestRequest. I use a loading screen during the request, which works well and without any issues on my local computer, but on the online App, it sometimes get stuck on the loading, when I make the same request several times. I don't know what the issue here is.

Here is the code:

```
private async Task MakeRequest(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value != null)
    {
        AppState.IsBusy = true;

        List.Clear();

        foreach (var type in GetTypes())
        {
            var (result, error) = await Utility.GetDataAsync(e.Value, type);
            if (error.HasValue)
            {
                AppState.ErrorShow = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                List.AddRange(result);
            }
        }

        AppState.IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

`AppState` is a scoped service that holds the state of the app. If `IsBusy` changes, I call `NotifyStateChanged()` which invokes `StateHasChanged()` on my page. `Utility.GetDataAsync()` is the method that makes the RestRequest and parses the result:

```
public static async Task<(List<string>, Error?)> GetModelle(string buildYear, string brand, string type)
{
    Error? error = null;

    var client = new RestClient("");
    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(response.Content))
    {
        try
        {
            .. parse result ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = new Error();
        }
    }

    return (list, error);
}
```

The code for the loading screen on my page looks like this:

```
@if (AppState.IsBusy)
{
    <div class="overlay">
        <div id="floatingCirclesG">
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07"></div>
            <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**edit**:
I used Application Insights to kinda track it down.
The issue is that I sometimes get an `HttpRequestException` with the message `Received an invalid status code: 'Con'`, and thus response has no content, which leads to `JsonDocument.Parse(response.Content)` throwing an exception.

Although I know this now, I can't do anything about it, because even if I check this and return from the method, I can't send a correct request anymore, even if I call the method completely new with different parameters. I always get the same `HttpRequestException` with the same message. I don't know why this happens. Locally the call ALWAYS works both with a REST client and with my app.

The Exception I get, when the issue happens, is the following

```
Time    6:35:28 PM
Exception type  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Exception message   Received an invalid status code: 'Con'.
AspNetCoreEnvironment   Production
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Received an invalid status code: 'Con'.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ParseStatusLine(Span`1 line, HttpResponseMessage response)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

followed by

```
Time    6:35:28 PM
Duration    2.24 sec
Outgoing Command    GET /commons-dispatcher/services/eurotax/domain
Result code Faulted
AspNetCoreEnvironment   Production
Error   Received an invalid status code: 'Con'.
_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors (Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.1')
#########/commons-dispatcher/services/eurotax/domain?&domainType=vehicleBrand&buildYear=2011&propertyType=KFZP10
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Looks like it gets "connection refused" and somewhere it's trimmed down to 'con'

Comment: Yes, I think you are right and the error message should be "connection refused". I tried everything I could think of and my guess is that the server to which I make the request has a security feature activated that blocks me for some time when I make several calls. I contacted the other party about the issue and hope they can resolve it on their side. And try/catch works that my website doesn't get stuck, but I can't make further requests for some time anymore. So, I think I can't do much here.

Comment: I got a response from the service operator and he said that the service was meant for internal use only (whoops ‍♂️) and uses Google Recaptcha and/or Bearer Token. They are working on an external API, but that will take some time. I guess there is no way around Google Recaptcha and Bearer Token, right? So, I guess I have to wait.